# Toogle active class on selected link react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a menu list that opens a mega menu when you hover on a larger screen and click on smaller screens.

Now when the mega menu opens, I want to be able to add a custom class e.g active class so I can style the mega menu for mobile.

However, when I click on the link, it adds the class or id for all links. I want to add a class or id for the clicked link.

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import { Navbar, Nav, Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import { FaArrowRight } from "react-icons/fa";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import LogoTransparent from "../../images/logo/logo-reverse.png";
import LogoWhite from "../../images/logo/logo-white.png";

const TransparentNavbar = (props) => {
  // check if the background is transparent to return corresponding logo.
  let LogoType;
  if (props.bgLogo === "transparent") {
    LogoType = LogoTransparent;
  } else {
    LogoType = LogoWhite;
  }

  const [active, setActive] = useState(false)
  return (
    <Navbar
      collapseOnSelect
      expand={props.bgExpand}
      bg={props.bgIntrinsic}
      variant={props.bgVariant}
      sticky={props.bgSticky}
      fixed={props.bgFixed}
      className={props.bgColor}
    >
      <Container>
        <Navbar.Brand className="navbar-brand-margin" href="#home">
          <img
            src={LogoType}
            className="d-inline-block align-top"
            alt=""
          />
        </Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
          <Nav className="ml-auto">
            <Nav.Link id={active ? 'open' : ''} className={ props.bgtextColor + " " + props.bgExpandBtn} onClick={() => setActive(!active)} >
              About Us
              <div className="mega-menu">
                <div className="content">
                  <div className="col first-col">
                    <section>
                      <ul className="mega-links expandable">
                        <a
                          href="/about/company-overview"
                          className="mega-menu-links-white-bg"
                        >
                          <li>Company Overview</li>
                        </a>

                        <a
                          href="/about/partners"
                          className="mega-menu-links-white-bg"
                        >
                          <li>Partners</li>
                        </a>

                        <a
                          href="/about/mission-vision-core-values"
                          className="mega-menu-links-white-bg"
                        >
                          <li>Mission, Vision &amp; Core Values</li>
                        </a>

                        <a
                          href="/about/management-team"
                          className="mega-menu-links-white-bg"
                        >
                          <li>Management Team</li>
                        </a>
                        <a
                          href="/board-of-directors"
                          className="mega-menu-links-white-bg"
                        >
                          <li>Board of Directors</li>
                        </a>
                      </ul>
                    </section>
                  </div>

                  <div className="col second-col">
                    <section>
                      <div className="mega-menu-text">
                        <p>
                          We focus on delivering digital solutions to our
                          clients such that high value can be derived with a
                          huge ROI. We have experience and expertise in
                          providing such a digital transformation program to
                          alleviate clients' pain point and position such
                          clients for efficient and effective operation with a
                          high possibility of increasing their revenue and
                          profit at the same time.
                        </p>
                        <div className="mega-menu-button">
                          <Button
                            variant="outline-primary"
                            className="primary-mega-button shadow-none"
                          >
                            Read More &nbsp;
                            <FaArrowRight />
                          </Button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </section>
                  </div>

                  <div className="col third-col">
                    <section>
                      <h5 className="mega-menu-image-header-text">
                        *** Limited is a leading Africa Technology
                        and Digital Consulting Firm
                      </h5>
                      <a href="#" className="img-wrapper">
                        <span className="img">
                          <img
                            className="w-100"
                            src="https://picsum.photos/400?random=1"
                            alt="Random Image"
                          />
                        </span>
                      </a>
                    </section>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </Nav.Link>

            {/* Solutions links */}
            <Nav.Link id={active ? 'open' : ''} className={props.bgtextColor + " " + props.bgExpandBtn} onClick={() => setActive(!active)}>
              Solutions
              <div className="mega-menu">
                <div className="content">
                  <div className="col first-col">
                    <section>
                      <ul className="mega-links expandable">
                        <a
                          href="/about/company-overview"
                          className="mega-menu-links-white-bg"
                        >
                          <li>Digital Culture</li>
                        </a>

                        <a
                          href="/about/partners"
                          className="mega-menu-links-white-bg"
                        >
                          <li>Identity &amp; Access Management</li>
                        </a>

                        <a
                          href="/about/mission-vision-core-values"
                          className="mega-menu-links-white-bg"
                        >
                          <li>Cyber Security</li>
                        </a>

                        <a
                          href="/about/management-team"
                          className="mega-menu-links-white-bg"
                        >
                          <li>Management Team</li>
                        </a>
                        <a
                          href="/board-of-directors"
                          className="mega-menu-links-white-bg"
                        >
                          <li>DevOps Services</li>
                        </a>
                      </ul>
                    </section>
                  </div>
                  <div className="col second-col-link">
                    <section>
                      <ul className="mega-links second">
                        <a
                          href="/about/company-overview"
                          className="mega-menu-links-white-bg"
                        >
                          <li>Managed IT Infrastructure</li>
                        </a>

                        <a
                          href="/about/partners"
                          className="mega-menu-links-white-bg"
                        >
                          <li>Digital Transformation (DX)</li>
                        </a>

                        <a
                          href="/about/mission-vision-core-values"
                          className="mega-menu-links-white-bg"
                        >
                          <li>Technology Consulting &amp; Advisory Service</li>
                        </a>

                        <a
                          href="/about/management-team"
                          className="mega-menu-links-white-bg"
                        >
                          <li>Cloud Computing (Microsoft, SAP) Team</li>
                        </a>
                      </ul>
                    </section>
                  </div>

                  <div className="col third-col">
                    <section>
                      <h5 className="mega-menu-image-header-text">
                         is a leading Africa Technology
                        and Digital Consulting Firm
                      </h5>
                      <a href="#" className="img-wrapper">
                        <span className="img">
                          <img
                            className="w-100"
                            src="https://picsum.photos/400?random=1"
                            alt="Random Image"
                          />
                        </span>
                      </a>
                    </section>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </Nav.Link>

            
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
  );
};

export default TransparentNavbar;
```

I kind of have an idea how it should work but I don't know how to implement it, probably give it a unique id to map through the whole mega menu or some sort. At this point, any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: have a look at this question as it might be an issue already answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44695985/toggle-class-on-menu-items-with-reactjs

Answer (score 0):

try using NavLink from "react-router-dom"

```js
e.g

import {NavLink} from "react-router-dom"

<NavLink to="/about/company-overview" className="mega-menu-links-white-bg" >
  Company Overview
</NavLink>

instead of::
 
<a href="/about/company-overview" className="mega-menu-links-white-bg" > 
    <li> Company Overview </li>
 </a>
```